# Celery PeriodicTask per user

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm working on project which main future will be running periodically one type of async task for each user. Every user will be able to configure task (running daily, weekly etc. at specified time). Also task will use some data stored by user. Now I'm wondering which approach should be better: allow users to create own PeriodicTask (by using some restricted endpoint of course) or create single PeriodicTask (for example running every 5 minutes) which will iterate over all users and determine if task should be queued or not for current user? I think I will use AMPQ as broker.

Comment: Minimum timespan is daily? or it goes below that? If daily is minimum, can you set a single time to execute task for all the users? Like the task will run at 12:00AM no matter when the user created it (if the task is valid according to user time set)?

Comment: I edited main post  to be more clear - user also will be able to set time, for example one user may want to trigger task around 19:30 PM and another around 11:00 AM

Comment: I think it depends on how much delay is tolerable in the task execution. If 5 minutes are tolerable then you can go with single task approach. If delay is not suitable in your case then you should go with separate task fro each user approach.

Comment: And, assuming that I will user AMPQ as broker, there won't be scaling issues with per user approach? (ignoring task 
execution time cost)

Comment: Redis or RabbitMQ can handle millions of tasks in the queues so per user queuing should not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you, that's I wanted to hear (:

Answer (score 1):

periodic tasks scheduler in celery is not designed to handle thousands of scheduled tasks, so from performance perspective, much better solution is to have one task that is running at the smallest interval (e.g. if you allow user to sechedule dayly, weekly, monthly - running task daily is enough)

such approach is as well more stable - every time schedule changes, all of the schedule records are reloaded

plus is more secure because you do not expose or use any internal mechanisms for tasks execution